# ACCESS Query to T-SQL with Pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Greetings, I'm having a HARD time converting this query to T-SQL, I would appreciate any help

```
TRANSFORM Sum(ViewMaster.ServiceCount) AS SumOfServiceCount
SELECT ViewMaster.Response, Sum(ViewMaster.ServiceCount) AS [Total Of ServiceCount]
FROM ViewMaster
GROUP BY ViewMaster.Response
PIVOT ViewMaster.Month;
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the input and ouput?

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT Response, ServiceCount, Month
       FROM ViewMaster) VM
PIVOT(SUM(ServiceCount) FOR Month IN ('January','February',...,'December'))
```